# udev rules & dwmblocks

Tags: udev, arch, x-dwm

I'm using dwm as my window manager and dwmblocks as my status bar. I've created a udev rule to update the battery icon when plugin and unplugging the charger:

`ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="path/to/script.sh" ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="path/to/script.sh"`

Relevant dwmblocks line:

```
{"", "/home/mike/scripts/statusbar/battery", 60, 13}
```

script.sh contains the `/bin/pkill -SIGRTMIN+13 dwmblocks` signal to update the status bar.

My problem is that the status bar only updates when UNPLUGGING the charger not when plugin it for some reason. Any help?